# Bot Authentication in Teams deployed on Azure

Tags: authentication, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to deploy the nodejs not auth-code sample using manual deployment - through zip deploy. The bot does respond for the first few questions, but when it comes to authentication (using the dialog), it gets stuck and is not able to proceed further. The error it gives is : 
No webpage was found for the web address: azurewebsite/html/auth-start.html. But I have the public folder deployed on azure under kudu services. Please help.

The example used:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and how to [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Have you made changes to the code?Also, can you double check your deployment steps just in case you have missed any of the step?

Comment: @vanc Could you please check if you have specified the redirect-url correctly as specified [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node/blob/3e41c67af2d1b5bdfdf62ed69fc9c57ebbce94b4/src/views/tab/simple/simple.hbs#L87)?

Comment: Hello, I got the problem resolved through optimizing the code which took longer time. With ngrok the code was working fine, but while deploying on Azure, it gave plenty of warnings of timeout and thus didn't work. I moved my onload code on button click of adaptive cards and it worked. Thanks community for your help.